# How can I transfer money from my Canada Scotia bank account to any bank account

Tags: united-states, credit-card, canada, banking

Presently I'm in the U.S and I have some money in my Canadian Scotia bank account. How can i transfer a large sum of money from my Scotia bank account to another bank using my online banking

Comment: Have you asked your banks?  They should at least be able to tell you what options they support.

Comment: Just log in and send a "wire transfer".  Many banks actually do not have the facility to do that online: if your bank does not, you're stuffed, you cannot.  Simply phone the bank and ask if you can send a 'wire transfer" to the US.

Answer (score 1):

If the amount is large, "wire transfer" is usually the cheapest option. Mane banks have online option for it.

Comment: Scotiabank does not have online options for wire transfers. I know because I had to do a wire transfer in October and I had to come to the branch to do it. It's possible it could be done through a phone call to a branch.

Comment: OK, then you will need a branch visit to do a wire transfer.

Answer (score 0):

I’m in a very similar situation where I tried to move my money from Canadian TD bank account to a US bank account.
Wire transfers usually require personal visit and cannot be done over the phone (weird, but, yes, they require personal visit).
It seems that the best option might be to actually write yourself a check and deposit it to your US based bank account. This obviously requires that you have a USD account at ScotiaBank and order cheques for this USD account. If you have funds in CAD you can exchange any amount at the USD/CAD rate for $20 (and not 2%-3% percent that banks usually change for currency exchange) using norbert gambit. This however “costs” 3-5 days to settle the exchange, plus whatever time it would take the check to clear.
Another ootion (at least at TD, but perhaps it’s the same with Scotia) is to designate somebody who could come to the branch and make the wire transfer on your behalf.